# how to avoid the character conversion of WordPress pages?

Tags: pages, characters

I am trying to use the  WordPress pages but WordPress is overwriting certain characters.

the '>' character is turned into '& gt;'

why is WordPress changing these characters?
is it possible to turn character conversion off for certain pages?

Comment: I would ***STRONGLY*** recommend against plugins that allow PHP to be embedded in content

Answer (score 3):

What you are doing is incredibly dangerous. You can break your site horribly, or have your entire server hacked. With a PHP in content plugin there is nothing stopping an editor from copy pasting a PHP shell in to the content editor and taking full control of your site.

If you have content on a page and want to include custom code, you should use one of the following:

- shortcodes
- custom page templates
- hooks and filters, e.g. `the_content`
- custom template functions
- custom metaboxes and associated code

There are many alternatives, all well documented and with hundreds of questions asking how to do them from new developers on this site alone. I encourage you to ask!!

You should ***NEVER*** use plugins that let you put PHP code inside your posts. If I were to do this, I would face immediate dismissal from my job. I **urge** you to consider alternatives.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/lNEg8.gif

Comment: I need to include custom content and custom code on a certain page. I was asked to just use the WP pages inside the admin. I don't work on WP. thanks for the heads up but This page is for admin users only and there is no posts inside the entire website, it's read-only for public. i'll try to find a different solution. never answered my question though :P

Comment: "[You] never answered my question though" -- I would argue that "You should ***NEVER*** use plugins that let you put PHP code inside your posts" is your answer.

Comment: Even if your PHP in content plugin is restricted to a single person, in a single country, on a single browser, with a single login, at a particular time of day, of a certain age, on a certain browser, from a certain ISP, on a certain OS, it is still a cardinal sin. I can say without doubt that PHP in content is an abomination, and that I can say any word of any severity that I want and it would still be applicable. It is about the worst thing that you can ever do in any PHP application nevermind WordPress specific. I give you the benefit of the doubt as someone who knows no better